Const reference: variable used in loop condition not modified in loop body
I have some code like this:
    void splay(const size_t x) {
        for (const size_t& nxfa = nodes.at(x).father; nxfa;) {
            normalize(nxfa);
            const Node& nf = nodes.at(nxfa);
            if (nf.lch) normalize(nf.lch);
            if (nf.rch) normalize(nf.rch);
            rotate(x == nf.lch ? 'R' : 'L', x);
        }
    }

In the for-loop condition, clang-diagnostic-for-loop-analysis tool complains "variable 'nxfa' used in loop condition not modified in loop body."
However, inlined function call rotate will modify the object nxfa references to, just we do not use nxfa (the const_reference) to modify it.
It's a legal usage so just a false alarm by tool, correct? Thanks.
BTW, now I can workaround it by the following code:
    void splay(const size_t x) {
        while (nodes.at(x).father) {
            const size_t nxfa = nodes.at(x).father;
            normalize(nxfa);
            const Node& nf = nodes.at(nxfa);
            if (nf.lch) normalize(nf.lch);
            if (nf.rch) normalize(nf.rch);
            rotate(x == nf.lch ? 'R' : 'L', x);
        }
    }


What's rotate()?  Is it std::rotate(), std::ranges::rotate() or something else entirely?

nwhat normalize() or rotate() does? how defined? Sounds like it's a function with some very indirect side-effect you rely on, you may trick an optimizer into thinking it doesn't happen.

If I would do the code review, I would come to the exact same conclusion as the analyzer tool without knowing any context of what normalize() or rotate() do and whether they have side effects. I would prefer the second variant that you presented as workaround together with proper documentation. Coding is not only about legality, but also about readability and maintainability.

"code like this" - please provide [mcve]

It's not a false alarm by clang-diagnostic-for-loop-analysis tool.  The first code's loop either executes zero times, or infinite times.  (Barring an exception or exit / terminate / abort.)

Your second code snippet is far more readable - I'd include a comment in the loop body to tell the reader which line potentially modifies the stopping conditional.

Yes, this is legal. You should report a bug to your static analyzer.

Pardon me, but no statement (what is  normalize()?)  within that loop can change nxfa or in-loop variable nf without casting const away, which is UB. Second loop is quite legal and can be reworked in away that thereis no repeated call.

@Swift-FridayPie You're allowed to cast the const away, as long as the target object isn't actually const. That's what const_cast is for after all. (Or even without the cast, you can access the target object in some other way and modify it.)

Yeah, but ayhting like that can happen only dynamically, static analizer only sees a contract that they cannot be changed within loop. If such const_cast was visible to it (is it hiden inside normalize?), that's be other story. This code might be legal or not, impossible to say,  but it is designed to look like it isn't. It's an example why Torvalds  and a like him are hating C++. This is breach of contract.

@Swift-FridayPie I don't see an issue here, to be honest. The analyzer just shouldn't warn when the loop variable is a pointer/ref (and the condition dereferences it, as opposed to checking the address).

In first snippet nxfa  is const. Nothing can change it or it would be UB. Code would generated and can execute as if UB never happened.
In loop
  for (const size_t& nxfa = nodes.at(x).father; nxfa;)

the expression nodes.at(x).father evaluated exactly once, therefore nothing changes from iteration to iteration. You can write this as:
 {
     const size_t& nxfa = nodes.at(x).father
     while(nxfa) {  // this is a constant
        normalize(nxfa);                  // nxfa cannot be changed
        const Node& nf = nodes.at(nxfa);  // nf cannot be changed
        if (nf.lch) normalize(nf.lch);    // no change
        if (nf.rch) normalize(nf.rch);    // no change
        rotate(x == nf.lch ? 'R' : 'L', x);  // x change may be UB or not, but value never used again
     }
 }


I didn't downvote but assuming each object in nodes has a pointer that points back to nodes (which is not that unusual after all), it is quite possible that normalize(nf.lch) modifies nf.father without const_cast anywhere.

nxfa may reference either to const-qualified size_t or to non-const-qualified size_t. In the latter case referenced value may be changed.

int x = 32; const int& ref = x; x = 42; the value of ref changes from before and after the last statement. It is a constant reference, yet no problem. OP says the value is modified by rotate.

"In first snippet nxfa is const. Nothing can change it or it would be UB." That's not always true. If the object for which nxfa is a reference is non-const then the constness can be cast away.

@Bathsheba when the object is non-const then no const cast is needed. It can be modified, just not trough the const reference.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai yes, these are dynamic changes if rotate somehow can use x to change the object nxfa is referencing. Static analyzers do not take these in account , no dynamic or side effects, only visible global and local variable changes, it's not  a bug - it's a outside static anylisis boundaries. From point of view of static analysis this loop can execute 0 or infinite times
